# Most efficient way to find polynomial roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

Given a polynomial:
$$z^7+10z^6+42z^5+96z^4+129z^3+102z^2+44z+8$$
find it's roots. I started off by using Horner's method (I believe one of the roots has to be $1$, so that's my starting point) but there's an awful lot of computing here and we aren't allowed to have a calculator during the tests. Is there a more efficient way for doing this? And also , what are the most used ways for finding polynomial roots (I believe this question was asked before, and a hyperlink would be enough). Thanks.

Comment: If it's for a test without a calculator I would immediately try $x=1$ and $x=2$. I would also try them multiple times (using synthetic division) assuming they choose one that would work out easily. Also noticing the $8$ at the end of the equation I would assume there is a root of $(x-2)^3$

Comment: I ran that through Wolframalpha too just for grins and It says that the factors are $(x+1)^4(x+2)^3$. So it looks like my guess was right. Sorry I don't know a more mathematical answer to your question. I was just using the logic I use when I deal with the College Algebra class that I teach.

Comment: [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) ?

Comment: There is no point trying 1 or 2. All coefficients are positive.

Comment: Fmonkey2001, you expect me to believe you teach algebra, at any level, when you dont even recognize the fact that $x=1$ doesnt work, and that the factor $(x+1)^4$ implies a negative root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply Descartes rule of signs to see that there are no positive roots, and 7 negative roots.
Then use the rational roots theorem to find the possibilities for rational roots. 
Test the possibilities by synthetic division.  If you find a root, the quotient of the division will be a polynomial of lower degree and the remainder will be 0.
Apply the same method to the polynomial quotient, until you have identified all rational roots.